# Table cells as a password type

Tags: html, html-table, passwords

I would like to hide some information in my table in the same way that I can do it with an

```
<input type="password" placeholder="password">
```

but in this case in the `<td>` of one of my tables.
Is it possible to do it as simple as in the `input`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this, it works very well:

```css
.hidetext { -webkit-text-security: disc; /* Default */ }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidetext">text to hide</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you can also use one of these:

```
.hidetext { -webkit-text-security: none; }
.hidetext { -webkit-text-security: circle; }
.hidetext { -webkit-text-security: square; }
```

Comment: You can still inspect the text though and see its content

Answer (score 2):

Put this inside the td, the td and the input will stay hidden

`<input type="hidden" placeholder="test">`